# Copying cl_float2 to constant memory not working for Nvidia platform

Tags: opencl

When I try to copy an array of cl_float2 values to constant memory it does not work as expected for the Nvidia platform, the .y part seems to be zero. I do not get this problem for the AMD and Intel platforms.

```
// Host
c_Quadrature_Filter_1 = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, FILTER_SIZE * FILTER_SIZE * sizeof(cl_float2), NULL, &createBufferErrorQuadratureFilter1);

cl_float2* filter_temp = (cl_float2*)malloc(FILTER_SIZE * FILTER_SIZE * sizeof(cl_float2));
cl_float2 test;
test.s[0] = 3.0f;
test.s[1] = 13.0f;

for (int xx = 0; xx < FILTER_SIZE; xx++)
{
    for (int yy = 0; yy < FILTER_SIZE; yy++)
    {
        filter_temp[xx + yy * FILTER_SIZE].s[0] = test.s[0];
        filter_temp[xx + yy * FILTER_SIZE].s[1] = test.s[1];                        
    }
}

clEnqueueWriteBuffer(commandQueue, c_Quadrature_Filter_1, CL_TRUE, 0, FILTER_SIZE * FILTER_SIZE * sizeof(cl_float2), filter_temp, 0, NULL, NULL);
free(filter_temp);

//Device
__kernel(__global float2* Filter_Response, __constant float2* c_Quadrature_Filter_1, __private int DATA_W, __private int DATA_H, __private int DATA_D)
{
    int x = get_global_id(0);
    int y = get_global_id(1);
    int z = get_global_id(2);

    Filter_Response[Calculate3DIndex(x,y,z,DATA_W,DATA_H)].y = c_Quadrature_Filter_1[0].y;
}
```

Comment: Can you try using a `float4` and setting the last two components to zero? It's possible this is a bug with the NVidia implementation, I can't see anything wrong here.

Comment: Everything looks fine. Recheck the input and outputs outside the kernel. Is either that, or a driver bug.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I've never gotten the vector type math to work on the GTX680 and GTX260.  Because of this, some of the AMD libraries like the FFT don't work with NVIDIA cards but work fine on AMD and Intel hardware.  NVIDIA seems to be lagging on the OpenCL front.

Another thing to look at is the Preferred Vector Length for the OpenCL device to best utilize resources.  For example, my ATI7990 has float Preferred Vector Length of 1 and my i5 has a v Vector Length of 8.  Therefore, to fully utilize the i5, I'd be using float8 to maximize the use of SIMD.

To check Preferred Vector Length, use [`clGetDeviceInfo`](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html) with the CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_FLOAT option.

Edit:

Oops, the Native Vector Width is shown, but it is the same as the Preferred Vector Width.

[image]